# How to increase flavour intensity in this recipe?

Tags: vegetables, pasta

I am thinking of making dinner tonight (probably pasta) and the ingredients that I have a courgettes, tomatoes and half a butternut squash. I am 70% vegetarian

I first added olive oil, then fried onions and garlic, then added in the vegetables. I added in salt, pepper, souvlaki seasoning, sage and thyme I believe for extra taste. At the end I mixed in a tablespoon of Ricotta (my favourite cheese). The pasta I had with it was Rigatoni.

However the taste turned out to be a bit bland. What can I do to spice up this recipe? I want it to be more intense,perhaps roasting the vegetables first and then frying them. Will that help? Otherwise what can I add to increase its taste?

Thanks.

**Edit :** Instead of having pasta with this sauce, can I have Ciabatta baked in the oven with it?

Comment: I am sorry... but what would a 70% vegetarian be?

Comment: As written, this question is essentially [What can I add to X](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1091/41) and not constructive. It's also pretty bizarre in the sense of changing from future to past tense in the second paragraph. I can see how this *could* be constructive, if you were able to be more specific about what you mean by "more intense" - for example, bringing out the flavour of a specific ingredient, or just asking about the flavour of roasting vs. sautéeing these particular vegetables. But the current version is just going to lead to random poll-style answers, if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding some green, yellow and red peppers with the added vegetables. I believe these peppers give a strong taste.

Also you could try to add some paper laurel when cooking, then remove it upon serving, it gives a good taste and smell too.

Comment: Hey I roasted them in the oven and then pulverised them with the hand blender and the taste was a lot better!